# Batch replace colour images, except a specific colour on Linux

Tags: linux, background, icons, imagemagick

I have 456 .PNG icons with a white image on a blue background, but the background is pixelated. So when I use mogrify to replace a colour, lots of parts of the icon won't become the red colour I want, and stay in a shade of blue. Is there a way to replace all colours, all shades of blue, and keep the white icon intact? Because mogrify recolouring the icons would turn the whole icon red, even the white part.

I have a feeling the solution should be simple, but after some googling and some messing around with Imagemagick and Phatch, I can't seem to figure it out.

I kind of need a batch solution, since theming all the icons manually would be... Something I don't want to do.

I am open for any suggestions and I apologizs in advance if this question turns out to be a duplicate!

If you need more information, just ask, and I can give it to you!

Comment: How did the icons come to have their alpha channel replaced by blue in the first place? Where did they come from? Is it 0000FF blue?

Comment: The ImageMagick tool provides a whole bunch of command-line based image manipulation tools. I am not very well familiar with all of its capabilities, but this is the tool you want to look into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "+opaque color" option will select all colors except the named one, and turn them to the fill color.  Thus,

```
mogrify -fill red +opaque white *.png
```

will turn everything except the white pixels to red.

Comment: That worked brilliantly! I had a feeling the solution would be quite simple, and I feel very stupid for not finding this on the imagemagick website(after your response, I searched again and found the +opaque option...). Thank you.